# SQLite ROLLUP query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to get a summary of the balance per month within my database.  The table has the following fields

```
tran_date 

type (Income or Expense)

amount
```

I can get as far as retrieving the sum for each type for every month but want the sum for the whole month.  This is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%m%Y', tran_date), type, SUM(amount) FROM tran WHERE exclude = 0 GROUP BY tran_date, type
```

This returns

```
032013  Income  100

032013  Expense  200
```

I would like the summary on one row, in this example 032013  -100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the right `group by`.  This uses conditional aggregation, assuming that you want "income - expense":

```
SELECT strftime('%m%Y', tran_date), type,
       SUM(case when type = 'Income' then amount when type = 'Expense' then - amount end)
FROM tran WHERE exclude = 0
GROUP BY tran_date;
```

If you want just the full sum, then this is easier:

```
SELECT strftime('%m%Y', tran_date), type,
       SUM(amount)
FROM tran WHERE exclude = 0
GROUP BY tran_date;
```

Your original query returned type rows because "type" was in the `group by` clause.

Also, `distinct` is (almost) never needed with `group by`.

Comment: Thanks! I just wasn't sure how to calculate between the two types.